# how to encrypt file headers information in php which cannot be opened without decryption

Tags: php, csv, encryption

I have working on a project where I need to encrypt the file having csv data. I want to encrypt the file with its header information. So that if someone access the file and try to opened it, filesystem show an error that file content could not be readable or file contents corrupted etc. The only mean it will show the actual contents through decryption of file header information.

For reference please have a look at php code I am using for file data encryption (but required file itself encryption).

```
$key = "1234567891012131";
$fd = fopen("output.csv", "w+"); 
$inputd = file_get_contents("data.csv");
$inputd = base64_decode($inputd); 
$decrypted_datad = mcrypt_decrypt (MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $inputd, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
fwrite($fd, $decrypted_datad);
fclose($fd);
```

Please need help on it.

Comment: You could perhaps put it in a password-protected zip, otherwise the recipient of the file also needs a decryption program

Comment: @MarkBaker Application flow already have decryption option for authorized users.I only need to protect file being opened by unauthorized users.